# Eclipse how to select needed file for debug if one source file mentions from two projects within workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I have same structure of maven project

```
parent / child1
       / child2
       / child3 
       ...
       ...
```

Thus in my workspace I see next view of projects:

```
parent
child1
child2
child3
...
```

therefore file `child1/src/MyClass.java` can be found from

1. parent
2. child1

**But**

from `child1` it is file of source code

from `parent` it is just file where I cannot navigate over classes.

**My problem** - when I make debug - `Eclipse` uses version from parent - and it is very inconvenient.

How can I say Eclipse to use version from `child1` manually ?

**P.S**

I tryed to mark code path from parent as source - but I cannot make it(

right click on parent project:

[image]

### UPDATE

[image]

view from parent:

[image]

view from child:

[image]

There are different icons.

Comment: couldn't get your question? like `next view` ?? `from child1 it is file of source code`?? `from parent it is just file where I cannot navigate over classes.`??

Comment: you can right click on any folder in eclipse and select it *Use as Source Folder*   Is it clearly now? I added menu view in topic

Comment: @sakura I have edited question. Do you understand my question?

Comment: sorry, I can't check screen-shots now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to debug perspective veiw

[image]

select java file and right cilck:

[image]

select `Edit source lookup...`

[image]

and select checkbox `search for duplicates source file on the path`

Every time when eclipse will met duplicates files in your workspace you can choose needed file.

[image]